# rename filenames under a folder, make them shorter

Tags: shell

I have a folder contains many .ass files for subtitles of a TV show
but the file name is just too long:

> House.of.Cards.S01E01.WEBRip.720p.H.264.AAC.2.0-HoC.SOME-OTHER-THINGS.ass
>   House.of.Cards.S01E02.WEBRip.720p.H.264.AAC.2.0-HoC.SOME-OTHER-THINGS.ass
>   House.of.Cards.S01E03.WEBRip.720p.H.264.AAC.2.0-HoC.SOME-OTHER-THINGS.ass

now I just want to change them into shorter form:

> House.of.Cards.S01E01.ass
>   House.of.Cards.S01E02.ass
>   House.of.Cards.S01E03.ass

is there any simple way to do it? (may be via shell script)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Or if your only renaming this kind of file, you can use some tool like http://therenamer.com/

Comment: @vikingsteve careful, you might get a flag ;D

Comment: @hihell "Really delete this comment ?" ---> ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

there is a (not so) simple way to do it

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f//.H.*/}"; done
for f in *; do mv "$f" "$f.ass"; done
```

Comment: yeah, was just about to recommend reading up here, but you found it already it seems: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html